# Can not get size of ios screen properly, even though using code from other answers on stackoverflow

Tags: ios, swift

I can not get the proper size of my ios screen using swift even though I have found this same question answered already, the code doesnt work for me. It gives me a slightly smaller width than the actual width of my screen. The code I am using is

```
let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
```

and getting the height and width from that, but again it is making my nodes too small and not actually filling the screen.

```
backgroundGround.size = CGSizeMake(screenSize.size.width, self.frame.size.width/12)
```

Please help!

[image]

Comment: Explain exactly what your issue is. What values do you get and what values do you expect? BTW - you do realize you are using the width for the height, right?

Comment: And you might want to include an image to demonstrate just how much off your values are

Comment: I expect the sprite node to fill the screen width wise. And yes, I do know I am using width for height.

Comment: Also, at what point in the life cycle of your viewcontroller are you making the calls? Using autolayout? etc.

Comment: The method its in is called during didMoveToView

Comment: Can you show more code?

Comment: @Stefan what more do you want? This is the part I am having trouble with. I just need some way to get the actual width of the screen.

Comment: Is `screenSize` wrong?  That is the correct way to get it, but you should verify.  If it's not wrong, something else is changing the size of `backgroundGround`.  You could subclass it and just override the setter to see who might be changing it.

Comment: I think your code for getting the size is correct. Maybe it's called at the wrong place, maybe the node size is correct and the scene is to small, maybe the node size is correct bit the node just don't scale the image ... I can just guess at the moment

Comment: @i_am_jorf It is saying the screensize width is 375. Is this correct or too small? Its an iphone 6

Comment: Please refer to [The Ultimate Guide to iPhone Resolutions](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions).  375 might be an iPhone 6.